# NodeJS EJS engine showing undefined

Tags: node.js, ejs

I'm trying to figure out what is the issue with the undefined type in my table.

I have an array of objects with strings, I'm rendering it to HTML template  like this:

```
message.find({ }, function (err, docs) {
  res.render('table', {
    emails: docs
  });
});
```

First, I just wanted to show the "_id" of the object and it worked but when I have added more keys to my table it started to show undefined state.

Like shown here:
[image]

**Here is the code inside the HTML template:**

```
<tbody>
    <% emails.forEach(function(item) { %>
      <tr>
        <th><%= item._id %></th>
        <td><%= item.email %></td>
        <td><%= item.price %></td>
        <td><%= item.ShippingPrice %></td>
        <td><%= item.ItemName %></td>
        <td><%= item.content %></td>
      </tr>
    <% }); %>
  </tbody>
```

Here is the console log output from the find query:

```
{ _id: 57de4c3ef3a4b2c820336c97,
userId: '57de41efaa75cc6933218e57',
email: 'Netta Tzin',
price: '$30.0',
ItemName: 'Airplay Campaign - 1200',
messageId: '13f2339358995daa',
content: '...' }
```

Comment: Run a manual query in `mongo shell`, check whether the returning object has values or not.

Comment: It sounds like the keys are not correct. Could you post the result of console.log(docs); before the res.render()

Comment: But this output is an object and not an array?

Comment: @MichaelTroger nope. it's one of the object in the array..

Comment: Well, the key 'ShoppingPrice' is not in there? Also do you alter the 'price' before passing it to the template?

Comment: @MichaelTroger How can I alter? any function?

Comment: The template is looking fine to me. I just assumed you alter something, because with the object above there shouldn't be undefined when accessing 'price'. Also I wondered where you expect ShippingPrice to come from. With the shown object it will indeed be undefined. To me it looks like you're having problems with your data from the database. Meaning that the values you want to access are just not there. I don't have any other idea, sry!